# Setting the value of Server.ScriptTimout using a query string parameter

Tags: asp-classic, query-string

I had a weird behavior when I tried to set up an ASP page's **Server.ScriptTimeout** property's value using the value from a query string. I was originally setting up the page for 1 hour(3600) by retriving the value from a query string parameter, but the page ran only for 10 mins. After that it timed out.

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = Request.QueryString("timeOut")
```

But when I hard code the value to 3600, it works as expected.

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 3600
```

I'm neither able to explain nor understand the reason for this behavior.

Comment: All `Request(x)` values are strings. Does it work if you cast it to an int ? `Server.ScriptTimeout = CInt(Request.QueryString("timeOut"))`

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Yes I had the same doubt and used a CInt(), but it did not work.

Comment: Not that you need to post the code, but are you sure the timeout you saw (when it ran for 10 minutes before timing out) was your script, or was it perhaps a database timeout or other issue? Just a possibility. You should note also that your page setting cannot be lower than the IIS metabase value for the script timeout -- actually, it can be, but it will be ignored. IOW, you can increase the script timeout on your page, but you can't alter it BELOW the threshold set on the web server. $0.02, and you probably deserve change back on that.

Comment: @Bret I'm pretty sure this was the behavior. I tried all possible ways. When I set the value to 3600, it works, but when I retrieve the value 3600 from a query string parameter, the page time outs in 10 mins(note server.scriptTimeout had the value 3600). Its bizarre. I really wish it might have been one of the scenarios that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

A quick test shows it does work and it does accept the QS value for the time out

```
response.write("<br />" & Server.ScriptTimeout)
Server.ScriptTimeout = Request.QueryString("timeOut")
response.write("<br />" & Server.ScriptTimeout)
```

Does your script direct to a secondary page which does the processing if so the timeout will need to be set at the top of that page too.

Comment: Barry, that was my first things that I did to test this. The Server.ScriptTimeout was set to the value 3600 from the query string parameter, but the page timed out in 10 mins. But when I set the value to 3600, the page time outs in 1 hour.